# not opening video mpg file in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: video-player

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 on my desktop. But, the mpg video file is not opening here. I followed the command " sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras" but it is not showing anything when  is selected and put the enter button. below seeing 2% for long time. I forcefully closed the window. Then I started again but the same problem when  is selected and enter button is pressed.
Please help me how to solve this problem
Utpal Ghosh

Comment: Not really clear due to the way or the sequence of your narrative but I think you're having a problem when installing the extras? If so it's understandable. At some point it'll ask you to accept the Microsoft EULA for the extra fonts (totally unrelated to video codecs but part of the package) so you need to use TAB and then directional keys plus spacebar to select wherever applicable and Enter top confirm.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good results using VLC. Download VLC using the following commands:

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> and issue the following commands:

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install vlc
```

Now start VLC and open the mpg-file using that program.